# Struct data passed into pthread_create is incorrect when read

Tags: c, pthreads

In the below code I am trying to pass a struct into `pthread_create`. The struct is defined globally. It is then initialized before calling `pthread_create`.

```
// Global scope
struct dat_struct {
  char *dat[SIZE];
  int received[SIZE];
  int numreceived;
};
```

```
 // main
  struct dat_struct *data = malloc(sizeof(struct dat_struct));


  for (int i=0; i < nthreads; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < SIZE; j++) {
      data->received[j] = SIZE;
    }
    data->numreceived = 0;
    pthread_create(&thread_ids[i], NULL, thread_handler, (void*)&data);
  }
```

```
void *thread_handler(void *dat) {
  struct dat_struct *data = (struct dat*)dat;
  // If I read data->numreceived it returns a large negative or
  // something incorrect
  ...
  ...
```

In `thread_handler`, reading the data gives incorrect results. If I use gdb to check what is passed into `pthread_create`, it is different to what is being received on the other end.

Is there a fundamental issue in my code?

Comment: Sorry, that was just an error when typing out the question. I have added the initialization now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
struct dat_struct *data
```

This code

```
pthread_create(&thread_ids[i], NULL, thread_handler, (void*)&data);
```

passes a `struct dat_struct **` to the thread as a `void *`.  Note the double `**`.

Thus this is wrong:

```
void *thread_handler(void *dat) {
  struct dat_struct *data = (struct dat*)dat;
```

That code treats `dat` as a `struct dat_struct *` - but you passed a `struct dat_struct **`.  (I'm assuming the `(struct dat*)` is a typographical error).

You should create the thread with

```
pthread_create(&thread_ids[i], NULL, thread_handler, data);
```

and

```
void *thread_handler(void *dat) {
  struct dat_struct *data = dat;
```

Note that there is no need to cast to/from `void *` in C.